# Access authenticated data with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2 in an Angular2 project to do a very basic task, login and then show the logged in users information on the page.

The seemingly simple snag I've hit is that I need to know the users UID to request that data from Firebase (my permissions state can only access key inside "/users" with own UID - pretty standard).

I discovered in order to get the UID I need to subscribe to the af.auth observable and then inside there request the user data using af.auth.uid - which I've done successfully.

I've also noted that af.database.object creates another observable, which I can in theory access by piping with Asyc in my HTML. Issue is I can't seem to be able to get reference to the user's data obtained in the auth.subscribe, anywhere else in my App (specifically in the HTML).

I can console.log the subscribe of the user, which confirms I am getting the data.

Please correct my understanding or teach me how I can access this data, I am very very new to the concepts of Typescript and Observables.

Javascript Angular 2 Component

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Webroot';
  user: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    af.auth.subscribe(function(auth){
      if(auth != null){
        this.user = af.database.object("users/"+auth.uid)
        this.user.subscribe(user => console.log(user));
      }
      else{
        console.log("Auth is Null!")
      }
    });
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div> {{ (user | async | json) }} </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use arrow function `=>` to preserve `this` keyword:

```
 export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Webroot';
      user: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
      constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
        af.auth.subscribe((auth)=>{
          if(auth != null){
            this.user = af.database.object("users/"+auth.uid)
            this.user.subscribe(user => console.log(user));
          }
          else{
            console.log("Auth is Null!")
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

you can do better :

```
 @Injectable()
  class UserService{
     constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

     getUser(){
         return this.af.auth.switchMap((auth)=>{
            return this.af.database.object("users/"+auth.uid)
         });
     }
}



export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Webroot';
      user: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
      constructor(public userService: UserService) {
        this.userService
            .getUser()
            .subscribe(user => console.log(user));
      }
    }
```

use `ChangeDetectorRef` to force angular to update the view :

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private af: AngularFire,public userService: UserService,private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

 init(){
   this.userPublic = "Init";
   af.auth.subscribe((auth)=>{
          if(auth != null){
            this.getData(auth);
            this.userPublic = "Finish";
            this.ref.detectChanges(); 
          }
          else{
            //...
          }
        });

 }
}
```

Comment: Gahhh! I bloody knew it was to do with the this.user not referencing the correct property, but I just couldn't work out how to get it to flow out. I even had an arrow function to start with but changed to an annom function for clarity in my mind (new to arrow functions - turns out it's not the same as I had been lead to believe). 

Works a treat, thanks mate! Spent like 4 hours too many trying to understand what the hell was going on and why I couldn't reference the correct this.user instance! Legend!

Comment: I've been subbing to a FirebaseAuthState object for the uid and just plugging that into a path when I need user info from the database, but I like that this relies on a single sub to the database. Something a little strange happening here, though. If I assign  `getUser()` like this: `getUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user)`, and then attempt to subscribe to that observable, `this.user.subscribe(user => console.log(user))`, this.user is undefined.

Comment: I've reconstructed the code so that I have an init function that is called after the user auth is confirmed. It will then set properties of type observable on my data service so that I can subscribe to those observables elsewhere in my app. I seem to be losing reference to this.userPublic however I still can reference this.getData - which is confusing - http://pasteboard.co/Ph9BbNjIQ.png

Comment: add `public` before `userPublic`

Comment: Thanks! Is it better practise to assign the observable to a public property in the dataservice and just access it there, rather than returning multiple instances of the observable everytime the function is called in other parts of the app?

Comment: I've added public before userPublic however it didn't seem to make a change. The reference to `this` seems to change dramatically inside and outside of the subscribe as seen here where the debug statements are: http://pasteboard.co/PvWhZ0uEs.png

I also notice the HTML is bound to the userPublic property and only shows start, but the console logs the value Init for this.userPublic. Is there some reason the HTML wouldn't be updating like angulars $scope.apply().
http://pasteboard.co/Pw2ALDx4a.png

Comment: @AlexHarper use `ChangeDetectorRef ` see the update. wherever you change `userPublic` add `this.ref.detectChanges()` after it.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() throws errors "No Provider for ChangeDetectorRef!", and ApplicationRef.tick() complains about being called recursively, why would angular not be noticing updates to this property, I don't see any reason why it would be out of the regular change detection zone?