# angularfire2 can not read property 'displayName' of null

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am trying to process authentication using angularfire2. The [angularfire2 document in github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md) uses the Observable variable to get the current user's name. In the initial state when the user is not logged in, an error such as `Can not read property 'displayName' of null` appears. I'm curious to know what to do if you are not currently logged in.

[this is my Error Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxt5W.png)

And this is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  userName: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private afAuth:    AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
    this.items = db.list('items');

    this.user.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
      this.userName = user.displayName;
      console.log(`[constructor]userName : ${this.userName}`);
    });
  }

  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
     this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) the current user is either a `firebase.User` **or** `null`. My guess is that no user is signed in and therefore the current user is `null`.

Try wrapping an `if`-clause around it like so:

```
if (user !== null) {
  this.userName = user.displayName;
  console.log(`[constructor]userName : ${this.userName}`);
}
```

Comment: @YunHaPark please accept the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: @kucksdorfalex Oh sorry, This is my first Question, so I didn't know that I have to accept the answer. Anyway, I appreciated your kindness. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : [Access authenticated data with AngularFire2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788185/access-authenticated-data-with-angularfire2)

```
this.user.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
  if(user != null){
    this.userName = user.displayName;
    console.log(`[constructor]userName : ${this.userName}`);
  }
});
```

He use `if(user != null)` to avoid to face null error.

I would appreciate it if you know if this is the right method or if it is better than this.